# How to resolve Android External NFC CommunicationErrorException

Tags: android, nfc

I am writing Android application to read External NFC. Using following library and reader.

https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/

https://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/11155/ACS-EVK-Android-115-A.zip

Here is code:

```
private class TransmitTask extends
        AsyncTask<TransmitParams, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(TransmitParams... params) {
        byte[] command = {(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04};
        byte[] response = new byte[16];
        String hexID = "";
        try {
            mReader.power(params[0].slotNum, Reader.CARD_WARM_RESET);
            mReader.setProtocol(params[0].slotNum, Reader.PROTOCOL_TX);
            mReader.transmit(params[0].slotNum, command, command.length, response, response.length);
            hexID = toHexString(response);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "TransmitTask doInBackground : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return hexID;
    }
}
```

It is working good and reading NFC cards. But sometime It is showing following error,

> CommunicationErrorException : USB write error: -1

. (refer Image)

It resolves only when disconnect and reconnect NFC reader(USB). So how to resolve this without disconnecting NFC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are not closing the connection to the device once you finish to read, creating a new one that overlaps the previous one.

If you use a service to keep the reference to reader, then it is possible that the service is killed, when the connection is still up and when you create a new reader instance, you get an exception since that device is already in use.